# angular как скачать файл?

Tags: angular

вообщем вопрос простой, у меня есть   файл на сервере и путь к нему, хотелось бы просто предоставить ссылку на скачивание конечному пользователю, не передавая всякие блобы, т.к. размер файла большой и пихать его в блоб 32 гигов оперативы не хватает

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь аттрибутом `download`:

```
<a href="{{url}}" download>ссылко</a>
```

Это приведет к обычному скачиванию на диск.